# Issue with "TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null" in React Class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, class, components

I have created a react app through this command `npx create-react-app myApp`. I want to create a class inside `App.js` that extends `React.Component`. The problem is I am not able to fire up the app because the browser shows this error: 
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqGfs.jpg)

is there anything wrogn with creating classes in `App.js`?

Here is my code of App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

class App extends React.Component() {
render(){
  return (
    <div>
      Hello!
    </div>
  )
}
}

export default App;
```

Comment: omit the `()` at `React.Component()` to just have `class App extends React.Component {...` and see if the error still persists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a typo. Change to:

```
class App extends React.Component {
```

You seem to have `React.Component()`